# Truncate text to a specific digit Flutter Text widget

Tags: flutter

How to to Truncate text Widget on Flutter to speficic digits..and ends this text for example... "see more" or some dots"..."
See more or the dots can be connected with an AlertDialog widget to see complete text..
thanks to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below step

Step 1: Add DescriptionTextWidget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DescriptionTextWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;

  DescriptionTextWidget({this.text});

  @override
  _DescriptionTextWidgetState createState() => _DescriptionTextWidgetState();
}

class _DescriptionTextWidgetState extends State<DescriptionTextWidget>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin<DescriptionTextWidget> {
  bool isExpanded = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Column(children: <Widget>[
      AnimatedSize(
          vsync: this,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                isExpanded = !isExpanded;
              });
            },
            child: Container(
              child: RichText(
                text: TextSpan(
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
                  children: [
                    TextSpan(
                        text: isExpanded
                            ? widget.text
                            : ((widget.text.length > 350)
                                ? widget.text.substring(0, 350)
                                : widget.text),
                       ),
                    WidgetSpan(
                      alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.top,
                      child: (widget.text.length > 150)
                          ? Icon(
                              isExpanded
                                  ? Icons.keyboard_arrow_up
                                  : Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                              color: FFB1B1BD,
                              size: 25,
                            )
                          : Container(
                              width: 0,
                              height: 0,
                            ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ))
    ]);
  }
}
```

Step 2: Use

```
 DescriptionTextWidget(
        text:
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.",
      )
```

Comment: Yeah it is a great solution now, I try to remove the arrow and put some dots to expand the full text into an AlertDialog